# Python tox deps with patterned commands

Tags: python, unit-testing, tox

I'm using `tox` for my testing. Currently my `tox.ini` defines several commands:

```
commands =
    unit-a: py.test --cov mypackage mypackage/tests/unit/a []
    unit-b: py.test --cov mypackage mypackage/tests/unit/b []
    func: python -m behave -n "{env:SCENARIO}"
```

It also defines dependencies for each command:

```
deps =
    unit-a: mock
    unit-a: pytest==3.9.3
    unit-a: pytest-cov
    unit-a: pytest-sugar
    unit-b: mock
    unit-b: pytest==3.9.3
    unit-b: pytest-cov
    unit-b: pytest-sugar
    func: behave
```

This is clunky and redundant to me. Is there a way to use a pattern for the command to specify `deps`? E.g.,

```
deps =
    unit-*: mock
    unit-*: pytest==3.9.3
    unit-*: pytest-cov
    unit-*: pytest-sugar
    func: behave
```

Here's the error I get when trying that:

```
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code 1), logfile: /app/.tox/py3-unit-a/log/py3-unit-a.log
ERROR: actionid: py3-unit-a
msg: getenv
cmdargs: "/app/.tox/py3-unit-a/bin/pip install --progress-bar off --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple 'unit-*: mock' 'unit-*: pytest==3.9.3' 'unit-*: pytest-cov' 'unit-*: pytest-sugar'"

Invalid requirement: 'unit-*: mock'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simply:

```
deps =
    unit: mock pytest==3.9.3 pytest-cov pytest-sugar
    func: behave
```

The first line with `unit:` works because `tox` [splits factors](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#factors-and-factor-conditional-settings) by `-`.

You can also try negation:

```
deps =
    !func: mock pytest==3.9.3 pytest-cov pytest-sugar
    func: behave
```